# Setting up CUPS with a Canon ImageClass D1320 Printer, CUPS Wont Recognize?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cups

I am trying to set up CUPS so I can have wireless printing. The problem is, I cannot seem to find my model "ImageClass D1320" at all. First, there is no "ImageClass" in the selection as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQUmA.png

And there is no "MF" series in the list

I have found the support page for the printer: https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/d1320/imageclass-d1320?tab=drivers_downloads

But I cannot for the life of me understand how to install these drivers on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. The zip has a folder called "PPD" in the "Debian" folder but they are all .deb files! https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV6EM.png

How do I install these printer drivers?

Comment: It does not seem to be possible